# Unique continuity property

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone told me what is :"the unique continuity property"  in the following paragraph ?

and what is the meaning of : .... and either $v\in E(k)$ or $v\in E(k+1)$

Please help me

Thank you .

[image]

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: it's an article :Multiple periodic solutions of ordinary differential equations with double resonance ,how have I done to  send it to you?

Comment: (No, that's not necessary.) Unfortunately I do not know.

Comment: >_< , but who can help me ???

Comment: Hmm... The original reference seems to be *A unique continuation theorem for solutions of elliptic partial differential equations or inequalities of second order* by N Aronszajn - J. Math. pur. appl., IX. Sér., 1957, but the result is more general. "Unique continuity" or "unique continuation" seems to always indicate a result that ensures a function (typically, a solution to certain differential equations) is identically $0$ as long as it vanishes in a certain region. There does not seem to be a standard result that is always meant when the phrase is used.

Comment: i don't undersatand !